# Error : Datanode is running but not showing in admin report

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

I am installing a Hadoop cluster and when I start services and use JPS then I get this result in namenode.

```
[hadoop@hadoop-master Desktop]$ jps
5450 ResourceManager
5292 SecondaryNameNode
5708 Jps
5103 NameNode
```

and this in Datanode

```
2662 DataNode
2877Jps
2772 NodeManager
```

But Still my DataNode is not running or Configured. The AdminReport shows this

```
15/12/21 01:12:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
```

What can be wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Have you checked the logs of datanode? Some times it can happen and you might have to kill the datanode process and restart it.

Comment: I have checked the logs of Datanode. It showed me no Error.       

       
2015-12-21 14:41:27,925 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.0

Comment: Do you have namenode and datanode on the same machine?

Comment: No , Its configured on different machines. One namenode and one Datanode.

Comment: Hi @Vishal, did you fix it somehow? Do you remember what went wrong? Got the same error, running on 4 different servers.